# Videos not embedding for every user

Tags: facebook, video, meta-tags, embedding

We recently released a video service which is much social oriented, and facebook sharing is one of our key features.

All our meta tags are ok, and debugging with the facebook debugger, I get no errors, and it tells me that video embedding is enabled.

Although a lot of our users, and some people on our team, cannot play the video inline, and are redirected to the website. How come ? What is going on ?

We asked our community, and found that it has nothing to do with the browser, nor the OS, so how can I fix this ? I know Twitter requires SSL for its embedded players, could this be about security ?

Once again, video is playing inline for me, my associate is redirected to the website when he clicks the thumbnail...

Here is the link to our facebook page : http://facebook.com/cultcut
You will find a lot of examples of the video links I was talking about.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: It's probably going to be difficult for people to suggest solutions without seeing any of the code.

Comment: Yes of course, but what code should I paste in apart from the og meta tags ? I'll edit my question to include those...

Comment: Actually I can't access them now, but here is the link to the facebook page with a lot of links from our website shared there : http://facebook.com/cultcut

Thanks for your help!